# Owl Carousel Slider w/ autoWidth (Initial owl-stage issue)

Tags: html, jquery, css, owl-carousel, webflow

I'm using an owl carousel in Webflow and I can't figure out why it isn't working.

Here's the issue:

On the first load, the carousel looks like this:
[Image: On Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpbd4.png)

On refresh, it corrects a bit, but then is jumpy!
[Image: On Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkjRO.png)

After another refresh, it looks perfect and works perfectly.
[Image: On Refresh #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnG6T.png)

I tried to make the owl-stage have a min-width, but that completely disabled the slider. I've added a load function to fix some aspects of the slider but isn't perfect.
Here's a link for you to check out: https://edits-52c37b.webflow.io/product/circus-wood

Here's my code:

```
<script>
$(window).on('load',function() {

$('.projects-col-list.w-dyn-items').owlCarousel({

        margin: 8,
        center:true,
        nav: true,
        loop:true,
        autoWidth:true,
        animateIn:true,
        navText:["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide'></div>","<div class='nav-btn next-slide'></div>"],
        items:3     
  
             });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the same problem I solved this way - I hope it helps you too
setTimeout with ready function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.projects-col-list.w-dyn-items').owlCarousel({
      margin: 8,
      center:true,
      nav: true,
      loop:true,
      autoWidth:true,
      animateIn:true,
      navText:["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide'></div>","<div class='nav-btn next-slide'></div>"],
      items:3     
    }).fadeIn();
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
.projects-col-list.w-dyn-items {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey Emy, thanks so much, unfortunately now the slide is jumpy on initial and fixes after 1 reload. Anything else I can do to make the slider good on the initial load?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @Emy for helping me find the solution!

I found out that my owl-stage wasn't working with display: flex, so I changed it to display block, Now I added display flex to the collection list and it worked! Here's my code that worked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.projects-col-list.w-dyn-items').owlCarousel({
      margin: 8,
      center:true,
      nav: true,
      loop:true,
      autoWidth:true,
     animateIn:true,
      navText:["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide'></div>","<div class='nav-btn next-slide'></div>"],
      items:3     
    }).fadeIn();
  }, 1500);
});
```

I did not incude the code :

```
.projects-col-list.w-dyn-items {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

As it didn't seem to work for me. Hope this helps someone, I might make a tutorial for this so others can build a cool slider in webflow like this! :)